# Limit root login by IP Address?

Tags: command-line, ssh, login, security, root

Is there a mechanic to let me limit SSH and telnet logins to the root account based on IP address? I have 3 nets used for different things locally all in the 192.168.x ranges, I need to login from those and banned from anywhere else.  I know having root active is frowned on... but like a bad admin I live in my root account.

Comment: You mean SSH login?

Comment: Can't seem to edit my own question, but I need to cover telnet as well. I was hoping for 1 mechanic to fix both problems.  However it looks like they might be seperate answers.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer after looking at the related question, for SSH logins, sshd_config has the option for PermitRootLogin: yes/no.

create /etc/pam.d/telnet
 with the contents

```
auth    required        pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc     /ftpusers onerr=succeed

# Note: vsftpd handles anonymous logins on its own. Do not enable pam_ftp.so.  

# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth    required        pam_securetty.so
```

My example uses the same deny list as my ftpd